# ANTLR4 Python3 removing quotes from a string

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a rule to match a string in the grammar. I currently need the content of the string and not the quotes itself so I am looking to strip the quotation marks.

```
StringLiteral
  : UnterminatedStringLiteral '"'
  ;

UnterminatedStringLiteral
  : '"' (~["\\\r\n] | '\\' (. | EOF))*
  ;
```

I saw a solution on https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2687006/How+do+I+strip+quotes but it is an older version of ANTLR and I need to translate it into Python3. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ANTLR3 syntax:

```
STRING: '\"' CHARS '\"' {setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length()-1));} ;
```

still works in ANTLR4. If you want to port that Java code to Python, do this:

```
StringLiteral
  : UnterminatedStringLiteral '"' {self.text = self.text[1:-1]}
  ;
```

And if you also want to strip the `\` that are used to escape othe characters, do this:

```
grammar YourGrammarName;

@lexer::header {
import re
}

...

StringLiteral
  : UnterminatedStringLiteral '"' {self.text = re.sub(r'\\(.)', '\\1', self.text[1:-1])}
  ;
```